# Error on removing strings from a pandas data frame - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set and a function to remove the strings that are in the variable `'nstandar'`of my pandas data frame. The set, the function and the pandas data frame are the following:

```
setc={'adr','company','corporation','energy','etf','group','holdings','inc','international','ltd'}

def quitarc(x):
    x=''.join(a for a in x if a not in setc)
    return x

    Company name                         nstandar   
0   1-800-FLOWERS.COM                    1800flowerscom
1   1347 PROPERTY INS HLDGS INC          1347 property ins hldgs inc    
2   1ST CAPITAL BANK                     1st capital bank   
3   1ST CENTURY BANCSHARES INC           1st century bancshares inc 
4   1ST CONSTITUTION BANCORP             1st constitution bancorp   
5   1ST ENTERPRISE BANK                  1st enterprise bank    
6   1ST PACIFIC BANCORP                  1st pacific bancorp    
7   1ST SOURCE CORP                      1st source corporation 
8   1ST UNITED BANCORP INC               1st united bancorp inc 
9   21ST CENTURY ONCOLOGY HLDGS          21st century oncology hldgs
```

However, When  I create a new variable without the strings to remove, the new variable is just the same as `'nstandar'`. The code is the following:

```
cemp['newnstandar']=cemp['nstandar'].apply(quitarc)
```

So, What is my error? How Can I fix my codes?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I realized that the problem was with my function. So I modify it and its code is:

```
def quitarc(x):

    x=''.join(a + " " for a in x.split() if a not in setc)
    x=x.strip()
    return x
```